# Making (a, a) a Functor

Tags: haskell, types, functor, typeclass

How can I make `(a, a)` a `Functor` without resorting to a `newtype`?

Basically I want it to work like this:

```
instance Functor (a, a) where
  fmap f (x, y) = (f x, f y)
```

But of course that's not a legal way to express it:

```
Kind mis-match
The first argument of `Functor' should have kind `* -> *',
but `(a, a)' has kind `*'
In the instance declaration for `Functor (a, a)'
```

What I really want is a type-level function like this: `\a -> (a, a)` (invalid syntax). So a type alias, perhaps?

```
type V2 a = (a, a)
instance Functor V2 where
    fmap f (x, y) = (f x, f y)
```

I would think this would work, but it doesn't. First I get this complaint:

```
Illegal instance declaration for `Functor V2'
(All instance types must be of the form (T t1 ... tn)
 where T is not a synonym.
 Use -XTypeSynonymInstances if you want to disable this.)
In the instance declaration for `Functor V2'
```

If I follow the advice and add the `TypeSynonymInstances` extension, I get a new error:

```
Type synonym `V2' should have 1 argument, but has been given 0
In the instance declaration for `Functor V2'
```

Well, duh, that's the point! `V2` has kind `* -> *` which is what is required of a `Functor` instance. Well, ok, I can use a `newtype` like this:

```
newtype V2 a = V2 (a, a)
instance Functor V2 where
  fmap f (V2 (x, y)) = V2 (f x, f y)
```

But now I've got to sprinkle `V2`s liberally throughout my code instead of just being able to deal with simple tuples, which kind of defeats the point of making it a `Functor`; at that point I might as well make my own function `vmap :: (a -> b) -> (a, a) -> (b, b)`.

So is there any way to do this nicely, i.e. without a `newtype`?

Comment: When would you want to make tuples a Functor like this? It seems to me that if you need uber-Functor powers to operate on special-case tuples, you should probably be using a custom data structure, rather than tuples, in the first place. What do the tuples you are manipulating represent?

Comment: @Dan I don't _need_ "uber-Functor powers", it just would've been mildly convenient, seemed like it should be possible, and if it's not I'm curious why.

Comment: @pelotom I agree that it seems like it should be possible, though it appears that it is not. I just thought I would take a moment to get on my soapbox and preach the goodness of making an expressive structure tailored to your problem, rather than overloading tuples.

Comment: @pelotom: The thing you're looking for is typically called "type-level lambdas"; as you've noticed, there aren't any in Haskell.  [This other StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069840/lambda-for-type-expressions-in-haskell) has some related information.

Comment: @Antal, thanks for the link, very informative

Comment: @DanBurton: I'm not the OP, but for example, Functor/Traversable instances for tuples would be handy for use with the [automatic differentiation library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ad) (say, if your functions have known low dimension and you don't want to use lists/vectors).

Comment: [`Bifunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-3.2.0.1/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html) is the solution, to my mind.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As others have stated, there's no way to do this without resorting to newtypes or data declarations.  However, have you looked at `Control.Arrow`?  Many of those functions are very useful with tuples, for example:

```
vmap :: (a -> b) -> (a,a) -> (b,b)
vmap f = f *** f
```

Comment: Better is `vmap = join (***)`

Answer (score 4):

You can declare

```
instance Functor ((,) a) where
  ...
```

However that doesn't constrain the first element of your pair, and `fmap` would only act on the second element.

The issue is that a tuple doesn't enforce a relationship between the types of the two elements.

If you don't want a `newtype` decorator you can make your own fresh type:

```
data Pair a = P a a

instance Functor Pair where
  ...
```

which will be easier to work with than a `newtype` around a tuple.

Comment: I don't want a functor that only acts on one of the elements of the tuple, I want a functor for `(a, a)`, which acts on both the first and second elements (because they have the same type). And I'm trying to avoid creating a new data type.

Comment: @pelotom, not possible.  Functor takes a data constructor argument, `* -> *`, and `(a,a)` is not one of those.  You've got to use a `newtype` or `data`.

Comment: @luqui I assume you mean they require a type constructor? That's about what I feared... but I see no reason why the type alias shouldn't work.

Comment: @pelotom, it is hard to explain.  Try to write a type inferencer that can handle instances of type synonyms.  It's very hard, if possible at all.

Comment: `instance Functor ((,) a)` is already in `Control.Monad.Instances`

Answer (score 0):

With [singletons](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) you can define a `Functor` type class for defunctionalized symbols (`Type ~> Type` instead of `Type -> Type`)

```
{-# Language ExplicitNamespaces, TypeApplications, TypeOperators, KindSignatures, ScopedTypeVariables, DataKinds, TypeInType, TypeFamilies, AllowAmbiguousTypes, InstanceSigs #-}

import Data.Kind (Type)
import Data.Singletons (type (~>), Apply)

class Functor' (f :: Type ~> Type) where
  fmap' :: (a -> a') -> (Apply f a -> Apply f a')

data Dup :: Type ~> Type

type instance Dup `Apply` a = (a, a)

instance Functor' Dup where
  fmap' :: (a -> a') -> ((a, a) -> (a', a'))
  fmap' f (a1, a2) = (f a1, f a2)
```

This gives you a `Prelude.Functor` instance automatically

```
newtype f $ a = App (Apply f a)

instance Functor' f => Functor (($) f) where
  fmap :: (a -> a') -> (f $ a -> f $ a')
  fmap f (App fa) = App (fmap' @f f fa)
```