# Why is (a, a) not a functor?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functor, type-systems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making (a, a) a Functor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812633/making-a-a-a-functor)

I wrote the following implementation of quicksort:

```
import Data.List (partition)

quicksort [] = []

quicksort (x:xs) =
    let (smaller, notSmaller) = partition (< x) xs
    in  quicksort smaller ++ x : quicksort notSmaller
```

Then I wanted to abbreviate the two recursive calls to `quicksort` by applying `fmap` to the list pair:

```
quicksort (x:xs) =
    let (smaller, notSmaller) = fmap quicksort $ partition (< x) xs
    in  smaller ++ x : notSmaller
```

But apparently, `(a, a)` is not a functor. Why is that? I tried to provide one:

```
instance Functor (a, a) where
    fmap f (x, y) = (f x, f y)
```

But ghci did not like my attempt:

```
Kind mis-match
The first argument of `Functor' should have kind `* -> *',
but `(a, a)' has kind `*'
In the instance declaration for `Functor (a, a)'
```

Could anyone explain that error to me? I tried various "fixes", but none of them worked.

Is it possible to make `(a, a)` an instance of `Functor`? Or is the type system not expressive enough?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's important to realise that it's not `(a,a)` that would be the functor, in the same way that `Maybe a` and `[a]` aren't functors. Instead, the functors are `Maybe` and `[]`.

A full explanation requires introducing the concept of *kinds*, which are like "types of types". Any concrete type has kind `*`. A *type constructor* like `Maybe` or `[]` takes a type and returns another type, so it has kind `* -> *`.

What's the kind of `(,)` (the constructor for pairs)? It needs two types, one for the first slot and one for the second slot, so it has kind `* -> * -> *`.

You can only make a functor out of things of kind `* -> *`, so the short answer to your question is *no*, you can't make `(,)` into a functor.

However, you can get around the limitation by wrapping the type. For example

```
newtype Pair a = P (a,a)

instance Functor Pair where
    fmap f (P (x,y)) = P (f x, f y)
```

The newtype wrapper will be optimized away by the compiler, so this isn't any more expensive than what you were trying to do originally - it's just a little more verbose.

Comment: Aha, I tried `type Pair a = (a, a)` and that didn't work.

Comment: @FredOverflow `type` is just similar to `typedef` in C++; it doesn't create a new type, just an alias (so it wouldn't make any difference).