# Does this pipe tuple operator already exist* somewhere?

Tags: f#, operators, tuples, pipe

I'm aware of `(||>)` which does `(a' * 'b) -> ('a -> b' -> 'c) -> 'c`

But I've been finding this quite useful, and wondered if I was reinventing the wheel:

```
// ('a * 'a) -> ('a -> 'b) -> ('b * 'b)
let inline (|>>) (a,b) f = (f a, f b)
```

<sup>(*It can happen, I only discovered the [`ceil`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370402.aspx) function half an hour ago!)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

No, it doesn't.

However, you will encounter its variant very often if you use FParsec. Here is the type signature in FParsec documentation:

```
val (|>>): Parser<'a,'u> -> ('a -> 'b) -> Parser<'b,'u>
```

I think the library has a very well-designed set of operators which can be generalized for other purposes as well. The list of FParsec operators can be found [here](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/primitives.html).

I did a bit of digging; `|>>` operator doesn't seem to have [built-in Haskell counterpart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812633/making-a-a-a-functor) although it is easy to be defined using `Control.Arrow`.

Answer (score 4):

The operator you described is essentially the `map` function for a two-element tuple. The `map` function, in general has a signature (for some `F<'a>` which could be `seq<'a>` or many other types in F# libraries):

```
map : ('a -> 'b) -> F<'a> -> F<'b>
```

So, if you define `F<'a>` as a two element tuple, then your function is actually just `map` (if you flip the arguments):

```
type F<'a> = 'a * 'a
let map f (a, b) = (f a, f b)
```

The operation is not built-in anywhere in the F# library, but it is useful to realize that it actually matches a pattern that is quite common in F# libraries elsewhere (list, seq, array, etc.)

Looking at the Haskell answer referenced by @pad - in principle, Haskell makes it possible to define the same function for all types that support such operations using *type classes* (so you would write just `fmap` instead of `Seq.map` or instead of your `TwoElementTuple.map`, but it actually does not work for various technical reasons - so Haskellers need to call it differently).

In F#, this is not easily possible to define a single `map` function for different types, but you can still think of your function as a `map` for two-element tuples (even if you find it easier to give it a symbolic operator name, rather than the name `map`.)

Comment: Nice observation, I'll consider renaming it to `map`... but I must admit I like the piping semantics..

Comment: I think using symbolic name here is probably nicer - it really depends on your specific use. (But I'm not a big fan of symbolic names, in general, because I find them harder to decipher.)