# type parameter definition in scala

Tags: scala, scalaz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are type lambdas in Scala and what are their benefits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736164/what-are-type-lambdas-in-scala-and-what-are-their-benefits)

1. How to resolve this type definition: `Pure[({type ?[a]=(R, a)})#?]` ?
2. What are the reasons of using such construction?

Snipped comes from scalaz library:

```
trait Pure[P[_]] {
  def pure[A](a: => A): P[A]
}

object Pure {
  import Scalaz._
//...
  implicit def Tuple2Pure[R: Zero]: Pure[({type ?[a]=(R, a)})#?] = new Pure[({type ?[a]=(R, a)})#?] {
  def pure[A](a: => A) = (Ø, a)
  }

//...
}
```