# Accessing type constructor parameter of context bounds with higher kinded types

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types, context-bound

Is it possible to access the type constructor parameter of a higher-kinded type in a context bound? I am looking to define a trait that takes a higher-kinded type, and has a method that returns an instance of the constructor parameter.

```
case class A[TContents](c: TContents) {
  def foo = c
}

case class B[TContents](c: TContents) {
  def foo = c
}

trait Fooable[TClass[_ <: TContents], TContents] {
  def foo(obj: TClass[TContents]): TContents
}

case class AFooable[TContents] extends Fooable[A, TContents] {
  def foo(obj: A[TContents]) = obj.foo
}

case class BFooable[TContents] extends Fooable[B, TContents] {
  def foo(obj: B[TContents]) = obj.foo
}

class test {
  def getFoo[TType[_] : Fooable, TContents](obj: TType[TContents]): TContents = 
    implicitly[Fooable[TType, TContents]].foo(obj)

  implicit def aFooable = AFooable

  val a = A(1)
  val foo = getFoo(a)
}
```

This fails with compiler error complaining that context bounds cannot have two type parameters, but I cannot find another way to access the type constructor parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options—either use the [type lambda trick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8736164/334519) to partially apply `Fooable` (ugh):

```
def getFoo[TType[_]: ({type L[A[_]] = Fooable[A, TContents]})#L, TContents](
  obj: TType[TContents]
): TContents = implicitly[Fooable[TType, TContents]].foo(obj)
```

Or desugar the context bound (much nicer, in my opinion):

```
def getFoo[TType[_], TContents](obj: TType[TContents])(
  implicit ev: Fooable[TType, TContents]
): TContents = ev.foo(obj)
```

Note that in either case you'll need to give your `aFooable` a type parameter:

```
implicit def aFooable[A] = AFooable[A]
```

And I'd strongly advise obeying the warnings about parameter list-less case classes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. As I suspected, the syntactic sugar for context bounds cannot handle multiple type parameters. I wonder if this is oversight or a limitation of the language?

Comment: Lots of folks want partially applied types for different reasons (your case being one of them); see for example [this compiler plugin](https://github.com/non/kind-projector). To answer your question, though, I'd guess that it was a conscious decision to avoid yet more Scala syntax.