# How to write a scalaz.IsEmpty parameter for generic types

Tags: scala, generics, typeclass, scalaz, higher-kinded-types

I am trying to write a generic method that wraps anything that has an [`scalaz.IsEmpty`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/IsEmpty.scala) typeclass instance into an `Option`. It should return `None` for empty values, and wrap it into `Some` if it is non-empty. Here's what I've come up so far:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

def asOption0[C](c: C)(implicit ev: IsEmpty[({ type B[A] = C })#B]) =
  if (ev.isEmpty(c)) None else Some(c)

def asOption1[A, C[_]](c: C[A])(implicit ev: IsEmpty[C]) =
  if (ev.isEmpty(c)) None else Some(c)
```

`asOption0` works for primitive types like `String` (by using a [type lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736164/what-are-type-lambdas-in-scala-and-what-are-their-benefits) to indicate that `C` has the shape `B[_]`) and `asOption1` works for types with an unary type constructor like `List`:

```
scala> asOption0("")
res1: Option[String] = None

scala> asOption1(List(1,2,3))
res0: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3))

scala> asOption0(List(1,2,3))
<console>:17: error: could not find implicit value for parameter
                     ev: scalaz.IsEmpty[[A]List[Int]]

scala> asOption1("hello")
<console>:17: error: could not find implicit value for parameter
                     ev: scalaz.IsEmpty[Comparable]
```

Is it possible to write one method that works for `String`, `List`, and types of higher kind at the same time?

Comment: I see you changed your question. Could you explain what you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: @EECOLOR I changed the title to better match the last sentence of my question. I'd like to have a solution that works for any type of any kind, and not only for `*` and `* -> *`. That another "explicit" implicit conversion seems to be necessary for e.g. `Map` is unsatisfying. I do have the feeling that just providing the appropriate typeclass instance should be enough to use `asOption`. Sorry for the previous misleading title!

Comment: I edited my answer to add another solution. This however might still not be what you are looking for. If it is not, could you try to explain what you _are_ looking for?

Comment: @EECOLOR It seems that I found one answer to my question by using `scalaz.Unapply`. This solution does not require any additional implicit conversions but only an instance of `IsEmpty`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of [`scalaz.Unapply`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Unapply.scala) it is possible to write a generic `asOption` that works for many different types (those that are supported by `Unapply`) and that does not require any additional implicit conversions:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

def asOption[MA](ma: MA)(implicit U: Unapply[IsEmpty, MA]): Option[MA] =
  if (U.TC.isEmpty(U(ma))) None else Some(ma)

asOption("")              //> res0: Option[String] = None
asOption("hello")         //> res1: Option[String] = Some(hello)

asOption(List[Int]())     //> res2: Option[List[Int]] = None
asOption(List(1,2))       //> res3: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2))

asOption(Map[Int,Int]())  //> res4: Option[Map[Int,Int]] = None
asOption(Map(1 -> 2))     //> res5: Option[Map[Int,Int]] = Some(Map(1 -> 2))
```

Here is the first part of `Unapply`'s docstring:

> Represents a type `MA` that has been destructured into as a type constructor `M[_]`
>   applied to type `A`, along with a corresponding type class instance `TC[M]`.
>
> The implicit conversions in the companion object provide a means to obtain type class
>   instances for partially applied type constructors, in lieu of direct compiler support
>   as described in [SI-2712](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-2712).

Answer (score 4):

```
scala> asOption0(List(1,2,3))
<console>:17: error: could not find implicit value for parameter
                     ev: scalaz.IsEmpty[[A]List[Int]]
```

This error tells you that it can not find an `IsEmpty` instance for a list, and that is because the type parameter doesn't matter. Scalaz has an implicit for any list, regardless of the type parameter.

The method requests an `IsEmpty[List[Int]]` and Scalaz only has one available for `IsEmpty[List[_]]`. Since `IsEmpty` doesn't care about the contents of list, we just make the `asOption0` method happy by supplying a more detailed version of `IsEmpty`:

```
def asOption0[C](c: C)(implicit ev: IsEmpty[({ type B[_] = C })#B]) =
  if (ev.isEmpty(c)) None else Some(c)  

implicit def detailedIsEmpty[A, C[_]](implicit ev: IsEmpty[C]) =
  ev.asInstanceOf[IsEmpty[({ type B[_] = C[A] })#B]]


asOption0("test")             //> res0: Option[String] = Some(test)
asOption0(List(1, 2, 3))      //> res1: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(1, 2, 3))
asOption0("")                 //> res2: Option[String] = None
asOption0(List[Int]())        //> res3: Option[List[Int]] = None
```

---

### Edit

I took another look at the problem and found a solution that seems a bit cleaner. I fear it's not the result the OP is looking for.

```
trait IsEmptyLike[F] {
  def isEmpty(fa: F): Boolean
}

object IsEmptyLike {

  implicit def case0[A](implicit ev: IsEmpty[({ type B[_] = A })#B]) =
    new IsEmptyLike[A] {
      def isEmpty(fa: A): Boolean = ev.isEmpty(fa)
    }
  implicit def case1[A[_], B](implicit ev: IsEmpty[A]) =
    new IsEmptyLike[A[B]] {
      def isEmpty(fa: A[B]): Boolean = ev.isEmpty(fa)
    }
  implicit def case2[A[_, _], B, C](implicit ev: IsEmpty[({ type D[X] = A[B, X] })#D]) =
    new IsEmptyLike[A[B, C]] {
      def isEmpty(fa: A[B, C]): Boolean = ev.isEmpty(fa)
    }
}

def asOption[C](c: C)(implicit ev: IsEmptyLike[C]) =
  if (ev.isEmpty(c)) None else Some(c)
```

Comment: An implicit conversion of an implicit parameter... interesting! I've never seen that. If `asOption0` should also work for e.g. `Map`, another conversion seems to be required: https://gist.github.com/fthomas/4979797 But this raises the question why Scalaz provides an instance of `IsEmpty[({type F[V] = Map[K,V]})#F]` instead of `IsEmpty[({type F[_] = Map[K,V]})#F]` for `Map`.