# Is is possible to improve type inference for partially applied types in Scala?

Tags: scala, type-inference, scalaz

I'm trying to improve the type inference of the `traverse_` function in the code below:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

trait Applicative[AF[_]] {

  def ap[A, B](a: AF[A])(f: AF[A => B]): AF[B]

  def pure[A](a: A): AF[A]

  def fmap[A, B](a: AF[A])(f: A => B): AF[B]

}

def traverse_[AP[_]: Applicative, A](xs: Iterable[A])(f: A => AP[Unit]): AP[Unit] = {
  val ap = implicitly[Applicative[AP]]
  (xs :\ ap.pure(())) { (x, acc) =>
    val apFunc = ap.fmap(f(x))(a => identity[Unit] _)
    ap.ap(acc)(apFunc)
  }
}

implicit def optionAp = new Applicative[Option] {

  def ap[A, B](a: Option[A])(f: Option[A => B]): Option[B] = f flatMap (a map _)

  def pure[A](a: A) = Some(a)

  def fmap[A, B](a: Option[A])(f: A => B) = a map f

}

implicit def eitherAp[L] = new Applicative[({type l[x]=Either[L, x]})#l] {

  def ap[A, B](a: Either[L, A])(f: Either[L, A => B]): Either[L, B] = f.right flatMap (a.right map _)

  def pure[A](a: A) = Right(a)

  def fmap[A, B](a: Either[L, A])(f: A => B) = a.right map f

}

// silly, but compiles
val x = traverse_(1 to 10) {
  case 5 => None
  case _ => Some(())
}
println(x)

// also silly, but does not compile
val y = traverse_(1 to 10) {
  case 5 => Left("x")
  case _ => Right(())
}
println(y)
```

Running the above gives:

```
/Users/lodea/tmp/traverse.scala:49: error: no type parameters for method traverse_: (f: Int => AP[Unit])(implicit evidence$1: this.Applicative[AP])AP[Unit] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (Int => Product with Serializable with scala.util.Either[String,Unit])
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : Int => Product with Serializable with scala.util.Either[String,Unit]
 required: Int => ?AP

val y = traverse_(1 to 10) {
                 ^
/Users/lodea/tmp/traverse.scala:49: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int => Product with Serializable with scala.util.Either[String,Unit]
 required: Int => AP[Unit]
val y = traverse_(1 to 10) {
                           ^
two errors found
```

To get it to compile, I have to specify the type arguments to `traverse_`:

```
val y = traverse_[({type l[x]=Either[String, x]})#l, Int](1 to 10) {
  case 5 => Left("x")
  case _ => Right(())
}
```

Is there a way I can restructure `traverse_`, or any other part of the code, to make the type inference work? When the types start getting more complex, this gets annoying fast.

Comment: Miles Sabin discovered a way of doing this, which is used in the implementation of `traverseU` in Scalaz. That sounds exactly like what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As pointed out by Ben James, you are looking for Miles Sabin's [`Unapply` trick](http://halcat0x15a.github.com/scalaz/core/target/scala-2.9.2/api/scalaz/Unapply.html). [Here](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Unapply.scala) it is in scalaz repo. [Here's](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Traverse.scala#L49) `traverseU`, implemented with its help. [Here](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/example/src/main/scala/scalaz/example/UnapplyInference.scala) are some example usages. And here's my sketchy (hopefully correct) implementation for your particular case (note: I've renamed your `Applicative` to `ApplicativeTest` not to interfere with `Applicative`, defined in scalaz):

```
scalaz> core/console
[warn] Credentials file /home/folone/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_15).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

import scalaz._

trait ApplicativeTest[AF[_]] {
  def ap[A, B](a: AF[A])(f: AF[A => B]): AF[B]
  def pure[A](a: A): AF[A]
  def fmap[A, B](a: AF[A])(f: A => B): AF[B]
}

def traverse_[AP, A](xs: Iterable[A])(f: A => AP)(implicit G: Unapply[ApplicativeTest, AP]): G.M[Unit] = {
  (xs :\ G.TC.pure(())) { (x, acc) =>
    val apFunc = G.TC.fmap(G(f(x)))(a => identity[Unit] _)
    G.TC.ap(acc)(apFunc)
  }
}

implicit def optionAp = new ApplicativeTest[Option] {
  def ap[A, B](a: Option[A])(f: Option[A => B]): Option[B] = f flatMap (a map _)
  def pure[A](a: A) = Some(a)
  def fmap[A, B](a: Option[A])(f: A => B) = a map f
}

implicit def eitherAp[L]: ApplicativeTest[({type l[x]=Either[L, x]})#l] =
  new ApplicativeTest[({type l[x]=Either[L, x]})#l] {
    def ap[A, B](a: Either[L, A])(f: Either[L, A => B]): Either[L, B] = f.right flatMap (a.right map _)
    def pure[A](a: A) = Right(a)
    def fmap[A, B](a: Either[L, A])(f: A => B) = a.right map f
  }

implicit def iterAp = new ApplicativeTest[Iterable] {
  def ap[A, B](a: Iterable[A])(f: Iterable[A ⇒ B]): Iterable[B] = f flatMap(a map _)
  def pure[A](a: A) = Iterable(a)
  def fmap[A, B](a: Iterable[A])(f: A ⇒ B) = a map f
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

import scalaz._
defined trait ApplicativeTest
traverse_: [AP, A](xs: Iterable[A])(f: A => AP)(implicit G: scalaz.Unapply[ApplicativeTest,AP])G.M[Unit]
optionAp: java.lang.Object with ApplicativeTest[Option]{def pure[A](a: A): Some[A]}
eitherAp: [L]=> ApplicativeTest[[x]Either[L,x]]
iterAp: java.lang.Object with ApplicativeTest[Iterable]

scala> val x = traverse_(1 to 10) {
     |   case 5 => None
     |   case _ => Some(())
     | }
x: Option[Unit] = None

scala> val y = traverse_(1 to 10) {
     |   case 5 => Left("x"): Either[String, Unit]
     |   case _ => Right(())
     | }
y: Either[String,Unit] = Left(x)
```

I still don't know how to make it infer `Either[String, Unit]` instead of `Product with Serializable with scala.util.Either[String,Unit]` other than strictly specify type in one of the cases like I did on this line: `case 5 => Left("x"): Either[String, Unit]`.

Comment: Here is another example of `Unapply` in action: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924707/how-to-write-a-scalaz-isempty-parameter-for-generic-types

Comment: Perfect, thanks! How Miles comes up with this stuff I'll never know.