# Context bounds with two generic parameters

Tags: scala, implicits

In Scala, I can use context bounds:

```
def sort[T : Ordered](t: Seq[T])
```

To mean the same thing as:

```
def sort[T](t: Seq[T])(implicit def Ordered[T])
```

What if I have a class with two generic parameters.  I.e. I want to be able to ensure that I have a `Writer[T, String]`.  Is there a syntax where I can use context bounds (`T : ...`) or do I need to have the implicit explicitly (that was fun to write).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it's possible! But not really very pretty:

```
trait Writer[T, O] {
  def write(t: T): O
}

def writeToString[T: ({ type L[x] = Writer[x, String] })#L](t: T) =
  implicitly[Writer[T, String]].write(t)

implicit object intToStringWriter extends Writer[Int, String] {
  def write(t: Int) = t.toString
}
```

And then:

```
scala> writeToString(1)
res0: String = 1
```

The `({ type L[x] = Writer[x, String] })#L` thing is called a [type lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8736164/334519). Sometimes they're very convenient (if [buggy](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6895?focusedCommentId=61697&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-61697)), but this definitely isn't one of those times. You're much better off with the explicit implicit.

Comment: I'll stick with the explicit implicit!