# Modeling a binary relationship between two types

Tags: scala, generics, typeclass, parametric-polymorphism, type-constructor

There are businesses and people. Users can either like or post a comment about a business but the same **can not** happen with a person. When a user posts something about a business or likes it, that business is called the `target` of that like or post:

```
trait TargetingRelation[TargetingType[_],TargetedType]

class Business

class Person

class Post[Target | TargetingRelation[Business,Post] ] {
  def target:Target
}

class Like[Target | TargetingRelation[Business,Like] ] {
  def target:Target
}
```

Here I'm inventing a `T | P[T]` notation meaning type parameter `T` such that it satisfies some property `P[T]` (or `T :|: P[T]` if it carries more type-appeal). Somewhere else in the code I want to have declarations like:

```
object canPostAboutBusiness extends TargetingRelation[Post,Business] 
object canLikeBusiness      extends TargetingRelation[Like,Business]
```

these objects are evidences actually, something like Haskell type-classes. So this would type check:

```
val p = new Post[Business]
val l = new Like[Business]
```

but **not** this one:

```
val p = new Post[Person]
val l = new Like[Person]
```

As far as my knowledge of Scala permits, I can't model this particular state of affairs in a satisfactory way. Now I insist that this is **not** sub-typing because Business is **not** a:

```
class Business extends 
  TargetingRelation[Post,Business] with 
  TargetingRelation[Like,Business]
```

As a matter of fact it is very desirable that `Business` remains totally ignorant of the `Post`. The relationship is actually outside of both `Post` and `Business`. Besides, I suppose the above code would not even compile to begin with since `Business` is inheriting from `TargetingRelation` twice. Insights are most welcome.

related : [Using a context bound in a class type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20440279/369489)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this in scala with something that acts like a typeclass using implicits. For example:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

trait TargetingRelation[A[_], B]

class Business
class Person

// Using explicitly declared implicit parameter:
class Post[T](implicit ev: TargetingRelation[Post, T])

// Using a "context bound". The syntax is a little hairy and uses
// a type lambda because TargetingRelation takes multiple type params
class Like[T : ({type S[x] = TargetingRelation[Like, x]})#S]

implicit object canPostAboutBusiness extends TargetingRelation[Post,Business]
implicit object canLikeBusiness      extends TargetingRelation[Like,Business]
```

Then you can instantiate the classes with `Business`

```
scala> val p = new Post[Business]
p: Post[Business] = Post@374c991a

scala> val l = new Like[Business]
l: Like[Business] = Like@1fd348f8
```

But not with `Person`

```
scala> val p1 = new Post[Person]
<console>:15: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: TargetingRelation[Post,Person]
       val p1 = new Post[Person]
                ^

scala> val p2 = new Like[Person]
<console>:15: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type TargetingRelation[Post,Person]
       val p2 = new Like[Person]
                ^
```

If you search from "scala typeclasses", you'll find plenty of [explanations of the details](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html) of how this works, but basically, you require the constructor to take an implicit parameter of the type `TargetingRelation[TargetingType[_],TargetedType]` and then place an implicit of that type in scope when constructing your class (`Post` or `Like`). The implicit serves as "evidence" that the `TargetedType` has an instance of the typeclass (and plays the role of the explicit dictionary of methods that get automatically passed around in other languages typeclass implementations).

In fact, scala has some synatic sugar to help with this, called the [Context Bound](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-and-view-bounds.html). This causes methods written as:

```
def a[A: B] = ???
```

to be translated to

```
def a[A](implicit ev: B[A]) = ???
```

In your particular example, the contexts bounds syntax is a little tricky because there are multiple type parameters, but it can be done as [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20131589/context-bounds-with-two-generic-parameters) describes.

Comment: Tnx. "you require the constructor to take an implicit parameter of the type TargetingRelation[TargetingType[_],TargetedType]" was the missing piece for me. Can you please point me to a reference on this technique of using context bounds in class parameters as opposed to methods ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any references that talk in depth specifically about using context bounds on class type parameters, but from the [language spec, section 7.4](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf): "A type parameter `A` of a method or *non-trait class* may also have one or more context bounds `A : T`." (emphasis mine)

Comment: any insights as to how the resulting implicit can be accessed inside the class ?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer to the question you linked, you can use the `implicitly` function to access the implicit from the context bound inside the class.

Comment: To improve usability, you could add an `@implicitNotFound` to the `TargetingRelation` type, [an example](http://suereth.blogspot.nl/2011/03/annotate-your-type-classes.html)