# Using a context bound in a class type parameter

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, parametric-polymorphism

I was under the impression that context bounds would work only on methods:

```
trait Target[T]

class Post {
  def pinTo[T : Target](t:T)
}
```

apparently context bounds can be used in `class` too (but not in `trait`):

```
trait Target[T]

class Post[T: Target] {
  def pintTo[T](t:T) 
}
```

Now I'm confused as to how the evidence can be provided to `Post`?

```
class Business
implicit object ev extends Target[Business] // is implicit necessary here ?

val p = new Post[Business] // ?? how do I provide ev ?
```

related to [Modeling a binary relationship between two types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20438322/369489)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `A: Foo` notation for context bounds is only a shortcut for asking for an implicit value parameter of type `Foo[A]`. Since traits do not have constructor value parameters, you *can not* use this with a trait:

```
trait Foo[A]

trait Bar[A: Foo] // "error: traits cannot have type parameters with context bounds..."
```

Whereas in classes it's possible:

```
class Bar[A: Foo] {
  def foo: Foo[A] = implicitly[Foo[A]]
}
```

Which is just a different way of writing

```
class Bar[A](implicit foo: Foo[A])
```

You provide the evidence like you do in any other normal method call:

```
new Bar[Int]()(new Foo[Int] {})  // explicitly
```

Or:

```
implicit val iFoo = new Foo[Int] {}

new Bar[Int]  // implicitly
```