# Can I specify constraints on type members of type parameters?

Tags: scala

Is it possible to defer type member constraints to the usage site?

```
trait Query {
  type Result
}
```

Pseudocode:

```
def fooRequiresAnyRefResults[Q <: Query, Q#Result <: AnyRef]()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't test it right now, but this should work :

`def f[Q <: Query {type Result <: AnyRef}]() = ...`

Comment: @LawrenceWagerfield How about accepting the answer? :)

Comment: Sorry, thought I had!

Comment: I take it that this means there's no way (in Scala 2.12), to declare the "<: AnyRef" constraint right at the type declaration, i.e. "trait Query { type Result <: AnyRef }"

Comment: @akauppi: I'm not sure what you mean, your code should compile just fine in scala 2.12

Comment: You are right. My case is ": Decoder" instead of the "<: AnyRef", and that one does not compile. This, however, would likely need a new SO question to be created.

Comment: It was explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440279/using-a-context-bound-in-a-class-type-parameter#20440368