# Scala: Generics For Return Type Seq[A] or Future[Seq[A]]

Tags: scala, generics, higher-kinded-types

**The Problem**

I have two classes that look like the following:

```
class Now {
  def do[A](f: Int => A): Seq[A]
}

class Later {
  def do[A](f: Int => A): Future[Seq[A]]
}
```

The only difference between the two classes is that Now returns a Seq and Later returns a Future Seq. I would like these two classes to share the same interface

**What I Have Tried**

This seemed like a perfect fit for higher-kinded types, considering how both Seq and Future[Seq] should only need one type parameter.

```
trait Do[F[_]] {
  def do[A](f: Int => A): F[A]
}

// Compiles
class Now extends Do[Seq] {
  def do[A](f: Int => A): Seq[A]
}

// Does not compile. "type Seq takes type parameters" and
// "scala.concurrent.Future[<error>] takes no type parameters, expected: one"
class Later extends Do[Future[Seq]] {
  def do[A](f: Int => A): Future[Seq[A]]
}
```

Am I using higher-kinded types incorrectly? Am I supplying Future[Seq] incorrectly? Is there a way to allow Now and Later to share the same interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need type composition:

```
trait Composition[F[_], G[_]] { type T[A] = F[G[A]] }

class Later extends Do[Composition[Future, Seq]#T] {
  def do[A](f: Int => A): Future[Seq[A]]
}
```

Or if you just need it in this one place

```
class Later extends Do[({ type T[A] = Future[Seq[A]] })#T] {
  def do[A](f: Int => A): Future[Seq[A]]
}
```

See [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/2406a0f039e4e515478536fb58974b97c04de3b8/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Composition.scala) (I could have sworn it included general type composition, but apparently not.)

Comment: Thank you. Does the method of referencing a type like that have a name? I have never seen it before and would like to read more about it.

Comment: @JakeGreene it's called a **type lambda**. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736164/what-are-type-lambdas-in-scala-and-what-are-their-benefits

Answer (score 1):

**I** believe you want this:

```
import scala.language.higherKinds
import scala.concurrent.Future

object Main {
  type Id[A] = A

  trait Do[F[_]] {
    // Notice the return type now contains `Seq`.
    def `do`[A](f: Int => A): F[Seq[A]]
  }

  class Now extends Do[Id] {
    override def `do`[A](f: Int => A): Seq[A] = ???
  }

  class Later extends Do[Future] {
    override def `do`[A](f: Int => A): Future[Seq[A]] = ???
  }
}
```

But if you want something more general, where the abstract method is fully generic in its return type, then the type composition answer of @AlexeyRomanov is the one you're looking for.

Comment: 'type Id[A] = A' is a nice little trick. I wonder if scalaz has such a thing already

Answer (score 1):

Alexey's solution is very clever and answers the question you made. However, I think you made the from question.

You started with these two interfaces:

```
class Now {
  def do[A](f: Int => A): Seq[A]
}

class Later {
  def do[A](f: Int => A): Future[Seq[A]]
}
```

and want to modify `Later` so it implements this:

```
trait Do[F[_]] {
  def do[A](f: Int => A): F[A]
}
```

However, you are losing an opportunity here to abstract away whether something is now or later. You should instead change `Do` to be like this:

```
trait Do[F[_]] {
  def do[A](f: Int => A): F[Seq[A]]
}
```

And change `Now` to this:

```
class Now {
  def do[A](f: Int => A): Need[Seq[A]]
}
```

Here, [Need](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/stable/7.0.4/doc/index.html#scalaz.Need%24) is a Scalaz monad that basically acts like a lazy identity to the object it contains. There are other alternatives in the same vein, but the point is that the only thing you need to know about `Future` and `Need` is that they are monads. You treat them the same, and you make the decision to use one or the other elsewhere.