# Type Aliases in Scala

Tags: scala

Reading [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/), I saw the following type alias:

```
type Const[M, B] = M

implicit def monoidApplicative[M](M: Monoid[M]) =
  new Applicative[({ type f[x] = Const[M, x] })#f] {
    def unit[A](a: => A): M = M.zero
    def map2[A,B,C](m1: M, m2: M)(f: (A,B) => C): M = M.op(m1,m2)
  }
```

What's the meaning of the `Const[M, x]` here as a type alias? My understanding is that, for the new `Applicative` being created, it has a `[M, B]` type where the `B` is specified at the function level.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are type lambdas in Scala and what are their benefits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736164/what-are-type-lambdas-in-scala-and-what-are-their-benefits)

Comment: @KevinWright, ah, so my question about `type aliases` is actually a question about `type lamdbas`...

Comment: Used in this way, yes, that particular alias is just part of a type lambda.

Comment: I don't think this question is about type lambdas. One needs to understand type lambdas to make sense of the meaning of `Const` here, but knowing type lambdas doesn't explain what `Const` is being used for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why this type alias was introduced -- good reason to go back to that book! :)

However, the meaning is simple. `Const` is something with two type parameters where the second type parameter doesn't matter. I'd expect it to be used somewhere that *expects* a type constructor with two type parameters, but, as it happens, it is not.

The expression `({ type f[x] = Const[M, x] })#f` is known as a *type lambda*, and it is used here (and in most places, as a matter of fact) to convert something that takes two type parameters, `Const`, into something that takes *one* type parameter!

Now, the interesting thing is that the type parameter being received is ignored, due to its position in `Const`, and, instead, `M`, which is a type parameter of the `monoidApplicative` definition, is used.

Note that `Applicative` expects something that takes a type parameter, and here we are working with an `M` where `Monoid[M]` exists. Two examples of such `M` would be `Int` and `String`, neither of which has a type parameter.

So, in a sense, we are cheating `Applicative` by a trick where the type parameter is ignored and the final type gets replaced by whatever you want, so you could have an `Applicative[Int]`, so to speak, despite `Int` not having a type parameter.

Comment: `the type parameter being received is ignored` - is that `B` in `type Const[M, B]`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith I meant `x` in `f[x]`, though `B` is obviously being ignored as well.

Answer (score 0):

`Const[M, x]` doesn't have any special meaning, you could equivalently inline its definition and write `{ type f[x] = M }`. `({ type f[x] = Const[M, x] })#f` defines a type-level function.

Comment: could you please say more about `type level function`, Alexey?