# How does Scala's type system compare to Java's?

Tags: java, scala, type-systems

In one of the Stack Overflow answers it is quoted that:

> Scala is a fully object oriented language, more so than Java, with one of the most advanced type systems available on non-research languages.

In what ways is Scala's type system more advanced than Java's?

Comment: I'm sorry but just saw a question that asks SO users to compare groovy scala and clojure and has 500+ up votes. I accept the question is broad but I don't want it to be branded unfit for SO

Comment: Thanks for down voting anyway

Comment: Scala's type system features—among others—variance annotations, path-dependent types, higher-kinded types, proper existential types, structural types, abstract types and singleton types. Java doesn't have any of these.

Comment: Well to add more context im learning Scala, so the question was broad but you sir rightfold now have given me a check list to follow, thanks a ton

Comment: just because there are 500+ people that *like* something in no way qualifies it as *on topic*, unfortunately it just means there are 500+ people that don't know or choose to ignore the rules of the site.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly fine question. It's objective, reasonably specific and fits the philosophy of the site: a database of programming-related knowledge in Q&A form. That the answer is longer than two paragraphs doesn't make it any less fitting.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Scala's type system can do pretty much everything Java's can (with some warts removed, like covariant arrays). In addition, it has the following features:

## Variance annotations

An abstract class `C` that is generic on `T` can be made a subtype of `C[U]` where `U` is a subtype or a supertype of `T`.

```
class C[+T] // C[T] <: C[U] iff T <: U
class D[-T] // C[T] <: C[U] iff U <: T
```

This is incredibly useful when passing around immutable data structures parameterised on the type of values they contain. For example, `List[String]` is a subtype of `List[Any]`.

Java uses wildcards for this, thereby moving taking care of this to the user of the API rather than the definer. This is suboptimal in many cases.

## Path-dependent types

In Java, a value of non-static inner class type stores a pointer to the object of the containing class type. In Scala this is also the case, except it also works this way in the type system. For example:

```
class P {
  class C { }
}

val x = new P
val y = new P
var z = new x.C
z = new y.C // type error; x.C and y.C are distinct types
```

Java lacks this feature; `x` and `y` both have type `P.C`.

## Higher-kinded types

A type cannot only be parameterised on another type but also on a type constructor:

```
trait Functor[F[_]] {
  def map[T, U](function: T => U)(functor: F[T]): F[U]
}
```

This is most useful in type classes like `Functor` and `Monad`.

Java lacks this feature.

## Structural types

A type is a subtype of a structural type if it contains all members of the structural type.

```
type S = { def x: String; def y: Int }

class A { def x = "a"; def y = 1 }
class B { def y = 1 }
```

Here, `A` is a subtype of `S` because it defines both `def x: String` and `def y: Int` which are required by `S`. `B` is not a subtype of `S` because `B` does not define `def y: Int`. Note that in many cases, reflection is used when accessing members of values of which the static type is a structural type, and therefore structural typing is often discouraged.

They can be used to simulate [type lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736164/what-are-type-lambdas-in-scala-and-what-are-their-benefits), though, without runtime cost.

Java lacks this feature, and it's arguably not very useful anyway.

## Abstract types

Like methods, types can be abstract:

```
trait T {
  type G
  def f: G
}

class C extends T {
  override type G = Int
  override def f = 42
}
```

Java lacks this feature.

## Singleton types

The singleton type of `x` contains `x` and only `x`. This can be useful in particular when one wants to guarantee that a method returns `this`:

```
trait T {
  def x: this.type
}

class C extends T {
  def x = this
}

val x: T = new C
x.x // has type x.type (which is a subtype of C), not type T
```

In Java this isn't possible; you either have to parameterise `T` and rely on CRTP, or have `x` return `T` instead of `C`.

## Bottom type

Scala has the bottom type `Nothing` that is a subtype of all types and contains no values. This is the type of `throw` expressions and the return type of functions that never return (i.e. always throw an exception or enter an infinite loop).

Java lacks this feature and uses `void` instead. Scala has no `void` but makes the distinction between functions that return no value and non-returning functions explicit.