# Function monad type parameter

Tags: scala, monads

I've been checking [Atlassian Typeclassopedia](http://typeclassopedia.bitbucket.org) for Scala (examples using Scalaz) and I don't understand the function monad definition (I've never seen such syntax for type parameters):

```
implicit def FunctionMonad[R] = new Monad[({type l[a] = R=>a})#l] {
  def >>=[A, B](fa: R => A)(f: A => R => B) : R => B = (x => f(fa(x))(x))
  ...
}
```

Could someone please elaborate on what `{type l[a] = R=>a})#l` actually does?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736164/what-are-type-lambdas-in-scala-and-what-are-their-benefits hth

Comment: Thanks @Gavin, never heard of type lambdas. I am afraid this is a duplicated question then...