# Higher kinded types scala for List, Options and other complex types

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types

I am still learning Scala - So please forgive me if this is extremely simple to accomplish. I am also not very fluent with Scalaz or Shapeless - I am only beginning to explore those libraries. I am looking for a simple treatise somewhere which explains to me how I can do something like

```
trait AmazingMalini[F[G[_]]] {
      def fMap[A,B](aa: F[G[A]])(f : A => F[G[B]]) : F[G[B]] 
}
```

And then I wanna be able to do something like this -

```
trait SomeCrazyMagicWithList extends  AmazingMalini[Option[List]]{
   def fMap[A,B](aa: Option[List[A]])(f : A => Option[List[B]]) :Option[List[B]] =  ???
}
```

Note that option or list types are just examples I have a few container types that I would replace there in mind (building a small graph traversal like DSL for for an app).

Comment: I am not sure if that is correct solution but seems to work: `trait AmazingMalini[F[G], G[_]]`, `trait SomeCrazyMagicWithList extends  AmazingMalini[Option, List]`. Rest of code unchanged.

Comment: I would avoid using the same identifier `G` for distinct things, it's rather confusing. In other words, it would be better to just do `AmazingMalini[F[_], G[_]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change the signature of `AmazingMalini` to `trait AmazingMalini[F[_], G[_]]`

The method could then be implemented like this:

```
trait AmazingMalini[F[_], G[_]] {
 def fMap[A,B](aa: F[G[A]])(f : A => F[G[B]]) : F[G[B]]
}

trait SomeCrazyMagicWithList extends AmazingMalini[Option, List] {
  def fMap[A, B](aa: Option[List[A]])(f: A => Option[List[B]]): Option[List[B]] =
    aa.flatMap {
      _ match {
        case Nil         => Some(Nil)
        case as: List[A] => as.map(f).reduce(concat(_, _))
      }
    }

  def concat[A](x: Option[List[A]], y: Option[List[A]]): Option[List[A]] = for {
    xs <- x
    ys <- y
  } yield xs ++ ys
}
```

Note that Scalaz provides [*monad transformers*](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Monad+transformers.html) to enable stacking of certain monads. For example:

- the `OptionT` transformer enables stacking of any monad on top of `Option`: `List[Option[A]]`, `Future[Option[A]]`, etc.
- the `ListT` transformer enables stacking of any monad on top of `List`: `Option[List[A]]`, `Future[List[A]]`.

So, in your case, you could use [`ListT`](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/scalaz/scalaz_2.11/7.1.3/scalaz_2.11-7.1.3-javadoc.jar/!/index.html#scalaz.ListT) like this:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import ListT._

listT(List(1,2,3).some).flatMap(i => listT(List(i, i * 3).some))

res0: scalaz.ListT[Option,Int] = ListT(Some(List(1, 3, 2, 6, 3, 9)))
```

You can also use for-comprehensions with monad transformers:

```
for {
  x <- listT(List(1,2).some)
  y <- listT(List(3,4).some)
} yield x + y

res2: scalaz.ListT[Option,Int] = ListT(Some(List(4, 5, 5, 6)))
```

Comment: good answer - I was hoping somebody would sneak in lambda trick - and hence explain the syntax to me ...but this works ;-)

Comment: @user1525079 I think you meant the "type lambda" trick :P [See this post for an explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736164/what-are-type-lambdas-in-scala-and-what-are-their-benefits).

Comment: yea type lambda trick ... thanks, yea I saw that ... thanks again.