# How can I have a negation type in Scala?

Tags: scala, type-systems

I want to do something like this:

```
def iDontLikeStrings(arg: Not[String]) = {....}
```

Basically, this should compile:

```
iDontLikeStrings(23) 
iDontLikeStrings(true)
```

And this should NOT compile:

```
iDontLikeStrings("hello")
```

Comment: Just curious, can you give a practical example of when you'd use this?

Comment: Hardly ever - negation type is one tiny step above `Any` :)

Comment: Not sure it's even a step - Infinity minus one is still infinity!

Comment: @ChrisMartin: Something like this:
`
trait Sensitive //marker trait for any class containing sensitive info

def sendToUser(a: Not[Sensitive])
`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my implementation (see [gist](https://gist.github.com/pathikrit/0c2538fa8faec51fc2f23b9c5e4194c9)):

Step 1: Encoding to capture A is not a subtype of B

```
trait NotSubTypeOf[A, B]
```

Note: We can use infix notation to write `A NotSubTypeOf B` instead of `NotSubTypeOf[A, B]`

Step 2: Evidence for any two arbitrary types A and B, A is not a subtype of B

```
implicit def isSub[A, B]: A NotSubTypeOf B = null
```

Step 3: Define ambigious implicits to trigger compile error in case A is a subtype of B (or A =:= B)

```
implicit def iSubAmbig1[A, B >: A]: A NotSubTypeOf B = null
implicit def iSubAmbig2[A, B >: A]: A NotSubTypeOf B = null
```

Step 4: Define a [type-lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736164/what-are-type-lambdas-in-scala-and-what-are-their-benefits) for the negation type:

```
type Not[T] = {
  type L[U] = U NotSubTypeOf T
}
```

With [kind-projector](https://github.com/non/kind-projector), this can be made much more readable.

Step 5: Done!

```
def iDontLikeStrings[A: Not[String]#L](a: A) = {
  println(a)
}

iDontLikeStrings(23)   // compiles
iDontLikeStrings(true) // compiles
//iDontLikeStrings("hello") // does not compile
```

The compiler error message for the last line can be made better in Scala 2.12 which addresses [SI-6806](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6806).

Also, all of this is built into [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless).

Comment: It works only if both types are statically known. It can be fooled with `def test[A](a :A) = foo(a); test("hello")`. The problem is not solvable in Scala 2 without macros.

Answer (score 2):

In scala 3 this has become fairly simple:

```scala
import scala.util.NotGiven

def iDontLikeStrings[T: [T] =>> NotGiven[T =:= String]](t: T) = {....}
```