# shapeless - using Mapped for wrapping to a type with 2 or more parameters

Tags: scala, shapeless

For example, I have

```
class C[T, U] { ... }
class D[T, L <: HList, M <: HList] { ... }
```

I want that if the `L` is for instance `U1 :: U2 :: U3 :: HNil`, the type of `M` to be `C[T, U1] :: C[T, U2] :: C[T, U3] :: HNil` (i.e. wrapping into constructor of `C`, where the `T` parameter is fixed, and `U` runs through the `L` list). However, `Mapped[L, C, M]` does not work because it requires `C` to have only 1 type parameter, and it has 2.

Defining an alias

```
type C1[U] = C[T, U]
```

does not work as well because `T` is a type parameter of `D`, so such a definition must be inside the body of `D`, and so it's not visible from `D`'s type parameters (i.e. from inside square brackets).

So, should I write my own implementation of `Mapped` or there exist some built-in solutions to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your trouble is `C` having 2 parameters instead of 1 and you want to avoid defining an alias you can use [type lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736164/what-are-type-lambdas-in-scala-and-what-are-their-benefits)

```
Mapped.Aux[L, ({ type l[U] = C[T, U] })#l, M]
```

or [kind-projector](https://github.com/non/kind-projector) compiler plugin

```
Mapped.Aux[L, C[T, ?], M]
```

Normally [type classes](https://blog.scalac.io/2017/04/19/typeclasses-in-scala.html) like `shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapped` should be used in implicit definitions like

```
class C[T, U] {
//    ...
}

class D[T, L <: HList, M <: HList] {
//    ...
}

object D {
  implicit def mkInstanceOfD[T, L <: HList, M <: HList](implicit 
    mapped: Mapped.Aux[L, C[T, ?], M]): D[T, L, M] = ???
//implicit def mkInstanceOfD[T, L <: HList, M <: HList](implicit 
//  mapped: Mapped.Aux[L, ({ type l[U] = C[T, U] })#l, M]): D[T, L, M] = ???
}
```