# Scalaz 7 how to use Functor with Function1

Tags: scala, scalaz, scalaz7

Hi i am starsting to learn Scalaz.

I want to get a function and map over it with another function.

although i am able to write this:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

import std.function._
import syntax.monad._

((x: Int) => x + 1) map {_ * 7}
```

and it works, when i use the explicit appraoch as per the examples in github project it does not work (see below)

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

import std.option._
import std.function._
import syntax.monad._

Functor[Function1[Int,Int]].map{x:Int => x * 4}{(x:Int) =>x * 7}
```

I get as error

> Error:(10, 17) Function1 takes two type parameters, expected: one
>   Functor[Function1].map{x:Int => x * 4}{(x:Int) =>x * 7}

I did inspired myself from an example in the doc that works

```
Functor[Option].map(Some("adsf"))(_.length)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding implicits of `((x: Int) => x * 4) map ((x: Int) => x * 7)` we get

```
ToFunctorOps(((x: Int) => x * 4))(function1Covariant) map ((x: Int) => x * 7)
```

Signature of [`function1Covariant`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/6dd033aaaa60e19e6013642dc793185b3ce51383/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/Function.scala#L131) is

```
implicit def function1Covariant[T]: Monad[T => ?] with ...
```

whilst signature of [Functor.apply](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/2c1056e3b5ce488c9b25d1b5a409949a89a69a11/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Functor.scala#L115) is

```
def apply[F[_]](implicit F: Functor[F]): Functor[F] = F
```

Substituting `F[_]` with `({type F[B] = Int => B})#F`, or using [`kind-projector`](https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2016/12/05/type-lambdas.html#kind-projector) with `Int => ?`, we make `apply` require implicit

```
Functor[Int => ?]
```

which is satisfied by `function1Covariant[Int]: Monad[Int => ?]` since `Monad` is a type of `Functor`. Thus we could write explicitly

```
Functor[({type F[B] = Int => B})#F].map((x: Int) => x * 4)((x: Int) => x * 7)
```

or using kind-projector as

```
Functor[Int => ?].map((x: Int) => x * 4)((x: Int) => x * 7)
```

Comment: Thank you that make total sense. At the same time, I am trying to learn the scalaz library as in how it is structure and where is what in term of package and how to put the different pieces together to get what you want. So in a sense I want to understand the logic. How come my version that does not use Functor explicitly worked and not the one that used it explicitly ? Somehow Functor is of FunctionN is supporter but not the way one would expect, I wonder why ? Or is there something I am missing ?

Comment: The latest versions of Scala support partial unification of type constructors. So when you let the compiler infer the types it can infer something equivalent to `({type F[B] = Int => B})#F`.

Comment: Got it. But then why is there not a typeclass for FunctionN like there is for Option which I get from std.option._, and what is std.function._ good for then ?

Comment: I think I was not completely accurate. The compiler can infer this even without partial unification. Anyway the point is that the type you provided explicitly was incorrect, but the compiler can infer the correct one, so that's why your first version worked.

Comment: I think I have got the answer to my question after checking a bit stackoverflow and other. Please can you confirm that my understanding is right ? It is a scala limitation that makes it something that can not be generically baked in the library in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I accepted the answer above because it solves the problem. It shows how to do what i wanted to do. Making a function a functor explicitly so as to map on it. However i was left a bit unsatisfied as to why i have to do this `({type F[B] = Int => B})#F` for function ? why it can't be fully generic, why the library does not provide that out of the box, instead of having the user do it.

I believe I have found the answer in the following posts:

[What are type lambdas in Scala and what are their benefits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736164/what-are-type-lambdas-in-scala-and-what-are-their-benefits)

[Why type lambdas?](http://like-a-boss.net/2014/09/27/type-lambda-in-scala.html)

Based on it I concluded that the library can not bake that for you whenever you do not have F[X] such as F[Int, INT] or Map[Int, INT]. One need to manually resort to Type lambdas which forces you to do something partial. Hence we can't have something generic baked in the library for FunctionX.