# Coerce phantom type

Tags: haskell, types, casting

I seem to have got myself stuck in an interesting edge-case of the language here. It's tricky to explain what I'm trying to do, so let me write it in code instead:

```
data Foobar x =
  Foo1 {field1 :: x, field2 :: String} |
  Foo2 {field1 :: x, field3 :: Int} |
  Foo3 {             field4 :: Bool} |
  Foo4 {             field2 :: String, field4 :: Bool}
```

As you can see, *some* constructors depend on `x`, but others do not. I'm trying to write a function similar to `fmap`:

```
transform :: (x -> y) -> Foobar x -> Foobar y
transform fn foobar =
  case foobar of
    Foo1 {} -> foobar {field1 = fn (field1 foobar)}
    Foo2 {} -> foobar {field1 = fn (field1 foobar)}
    _       -> foobar
```

As you can see, record syntax neatly lets me avoid having to rebuild the entire constructor, applying `fn` only where it is needed. Unfortunately, this breaks when `fn` is needed in *zero* places. In that case (i.e., the final alternative), the expression fails to type-check. It is quite clear to me *why* it fails - but I'm mystified as to how to *fix* this.

Obviously I could just write out the entire thing long-hand. That would work for this cut-down example, but the real application I'm trying to write is quite a lot larger. (About 25 constructors, some of them with upwards of 15 fields.)

Does anybody have any neat ideas on how I can fix this glitch?

Comment: Can you just add `deriving Functor` and let the compiler write all 25 cases for you?

Comment: @DanielWagner The real type has multiple type parameters - and I intend to write one `transform` function for each parameter. I don't know of any way to derive that.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4069840/485115) might be of interest to you.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov It looks like `Bifunctor` is exactly what I'm trying to implement. Shame you can't derive that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution (to save typing) is to use record wild cards:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards #-}
-- ...
case foobar of
   Foo4 {..} -> Foo4 {..}
```

Comment: Ooo, that's interesting... It seems the pragma also turns on some other stuff that I don't want, but if I put this just in the module that defines the transformation functions, it should be safe...

Answer (score 2):

You have to pattern match if you want to do this manually unfortunately. If you want to avoid so much work, a simple fix is

```
   {-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
   data Foo a = ...
     deriving(Functor)
```

Now we can write a safer form of `unsafeCoerce`

```
  coerceFoo :: Foo a -> Foo b
  coerceFoo = fmap (error "This shouldn't be used on a phantom type")
```

And use this in your example

```
_       -> coerceFoo foobar
```

Comment: Using a `newtype` to flip the parameter order... What an ingenious idea. I wonder if that actually works? I'll try it out...

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Drat it doesn't since we don't have a way to transform `b` in Foo.. never mind

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I'll stand by my "write some trivial coercing functions" suggestions since you'll their linear in the type parameters vs the constructors