# Scalaz Writer Monad and filterM

Tags: scala, haskell, scalaz, scalaz7

I am working my way through [learning scalaz](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/) and [Learn You A Haskell For Greater Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) and wonder how to translate the filterM example from LYAHFGG to Scala.

`fst $ runWriter $ filterM keepSmall [9,1,5,2,10,3]`

with `keepSmall` defined as

```
keepSmall :: Int -> Writer [String] Bool  
keepSmall x  
    | x < 4 = do  
        tell ["Keeping " ++ show x]  
        return True  
    | otherwise = do  
        tell [show x ++ " is too large, throwing it away"]  
        return False
```

My naive approach ends with compilation errors and I have no clue how to go around that issue!

```
    val keepSmall: (Int => WriterT[Id, Vector[String], Boolean]) = (x: Int) => 
      if (x < 4) for {
        _ <- Vector("Keeping " + x.shows).tell
      } yield true
      else for {
        _ <- Vector(x.shows + " is too large, throwing it away").tell
      } yield false

println(List(9,1,5,2,10,3) filterM keepSmall)
```

Compilation errors:

```
 Error:(182, 32) no type parameters for method filterM: (p: Int => M[Boolean])(implicit evidence$4: scalaz.Applicative[M])M[List[Int]] exist so that it can be applied to arguments (Int => scalaz.WriterT[scalaz.Scalaz.Id,Vector[String],Boolean])
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : Int => scalaz.WriterT[scalaz.Scalaz.Id,Vector[String],Boolean]
 required: Int => ?M[Boolean]
    println(List(9,1,5,2,10,3) filterM keepSmall)
                               ^
```

and

```
Error:(182, 40) type mismatch;
 found   : Int => scalaz.WriterT[scalaz.Scalaz.Id,Vector[String],Boolean]
 required: Int => M[Boolean]
    println(List(9,1,5,2,10,3) filterM keepSmall)
                                       ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to the fact that Scala can't really know how to fit a type with three *holes* into the argument expected by `filterM`, which has only one *hole* filled with a `Boolean`.

You could solve your problem using some weird type-lambda syntax like this (not tested, may not work):

```
val keepSmall: (Int => ({type L[T] = WriterT[Id, Vector[String], T]})#L) = ...
```

Or (much easier) by introducing a type alias as follows:

```
type MyWriter[T] = WriterT[Id, Vector[String], T]
val keepSmall: (Int => MyWriter[Boolean]) = ...
```

This will make sure that the kind of the argument expected by `filterM` matches with the kind of the argument you are providing.

Comment: The second ones does the thing, thanks! The first one does not compile - tried to fix it somehow but my knowledge is too limited atm.

Here is a reversed question to mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736164/what-are-type-lambdas-in-scala-and-what-are-their-benefits

I guess sth similar must be available in Haskell as well but not in the particular example of Writer, right?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069840/lambda-for-type-expressions-in-haskell

Comment: I don't know much about how Haskell deals with this but I suspect that it is a bit more flexible when partially applying types with multiple parameters. I'd like to know what is the failure for the type lambda.